# newtheorem report class with `part' as reset counter

Tags: numbering, punctuation, theorems, parts

Sorry i have no MWE for this question.

I have a `.dtx` class and looking at the `diff` between a previous "good" version and the present i have, there is nowhere some recollection about what exactly is wrong, but here it is. So i ask in the direction of more details about `part`.

Ok, so the class issues a `\renewtheorem{test}[part]{Name}`, and users create environments, for instance:

```
\begin{test}\label{abc}
  Ok.
\end{test}
```

But when typeset "`as in test (\ref{abc})`" instead of

> as in test (1)

(before) the document shows

> as in test (.1)`.

Not where, but *why* is that dot popping up there?

In a simplistic MWE, the part is not showing its presence w.r.t. dot in `\ref`.
What can cause the dot there? If i set `\renewcommand\thepart{100}` then `\ref{abc}` is `100.1`: still the dot!

Thank s.

Comment: Maybe it is how the numbering is defined and may be dependent on the section, chapter or part you are in. Check how the theorem style `test` is defined and whether you see a `.` there.

Comment: no `\theoremnumbering` for `test` environment is invoked, only `\theoremclass` and `\theoremstyle`.

Comment: Isn't the result you are getting because you are using `part` to start with. Seemingly you don't want the dot but that is what the theorem numbering will look like dependent on the part number you are in. If you remove the `part` section then probably the numbering will result as `1` without a dot. I really can't get what is what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, it seems it didn't do as above, but instead `\renewtheorem{test}{Name}[part]` (`part` at the end); i explicitly put them in order and it works. i know what is wrong: some `\ifthenelse` tests are missing. thank s a lot!

Comment: Why don't you post the answer to your question here? If you have resolved the issue that is the least you can do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3580/discussion-between-azetina-and-sjbiaga)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you state `\newtheorem{thm}[part]{Theorem}` you're telling LaTeX that the `thm` environment should use the `part` counter, rather than defining a new one just for the environment. Thus, assuming this is the first theorem and that no `\part` command has been issued, the code

```
\begin{thm}\label{abc}
Text
\end{thm}

This is the reference~(\ref{abc}).
```

would print

> **Theorem I** *Text*
>
> This is the reference (I).

You probably had

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[part]
```

which is completely different. In this case a `thm` counter is created and it resets whenever `part` is stepped. Moreover, `\thethm` is defined by

```
\newcommand\thethm{\thepart.\arabic{thm}}
```

and this explains your output. Indeed the `report` class defines

```
\newcommand\thepart{\Roman{part}}
```

and when you issue no `\part` command the counter's value is 0, so that `\thepart` prints nothing. That's why you get `.1` both as the theorem's number and in the references to it. Redefining `\renewcommand{\thepart}{100}` doesn't change the definition of `\thethm`, which will give `100.1`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.dtx` has the list `part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection` (of `\LaTex` counters), and a list of `ntheorem` environments/counters `a,b,c,d,e,...`; `b` can only use `a` as shared counter or a `\LaTeX` reset counter; `d` only `a,b,c`, and so. In cases of "*no shared counter*" among `a,b,c,...`, the `part` counter is used as sentinel, when `\renewtheorem{}{}` must be issued without shared or reset counter specified. The search in the `\LaTeX` list did not single this case out, in order to distinguish `part` from the other `chapter,section,subsubsection` cases.

Removing the `[part]` section as suggested distinguishes from the erroneuos "`[part]` last" as it was (confused) at start, and directed me to detect the line of code for the missing `\ifthenelse`.

NB: `part` is not involved in typesetting the `report` document.